# How to embed a font using FDT (AIR SDK 3.9) embedAsCFF="false" not recognised

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, air, fdt

I'm attempting to embed a font using FDT.  I notice that FDT doesn't recognise the embedAsCFF="false" parameter.

(see: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-1853?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel )

I'm doing something like this:-

```
[Embed(source="fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf", fontFamily="RobotoCondensedLight", embedAsCFF="false")]
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.htmlText = '<font face="RobotoCondensedLight">Hello</font>';
```

Without embedAsCFF, no text appears.  But RobotoCondensedLight is listed in `Font.enumerateFonts()`

With embedAsCFF - I get a compile errors: exception during transcoding, unable to build font 'RobotoCondensedLight', and Unable to transcode fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf.

I assume the problem is the embedAsCFF parameter - or is it something else?

How are people embedding fonts with FDT?

Comment: Please put your code inside code tags.

Comment: Try `tf.embedFonts` as false. In case of fonts being loaded, they are embedded in SWF, so no need of embedFonts.

Comment: @vesper - that didn't sound right to me - but I tried it anyway.  Without embedFonts = true it just falls back to a default font - not the embedded one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is to use the ASC 2.0 compiler.  While it doesn't work with the old compiler (and apparently, it doesn't work from the command line either) - but the new compiler fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

«I notice that FDT doesn't recognise the embedAsCFF="false" parameter.»

Well, I think that's the issue. 
As of Flex 4, you do need to set embedAsCFF to false for embedded fonts to work.

If FDT doesn't allow you to use it, you may want to give a try to a different IDE.